# exception: invalid operator $avg in mongoDB /

Tags: mongodb

Hello I am using mongoDB 2.6.11

and the query is:

```
db.companies.aggregate( [
{ $match: {  founded_year: { $eq: 2004 },  
    "funding_rounds.raised_amount": {$ne: null},  
     funding_rounds: { $size: 5 } } },
 { $project: { name:1,  
           _id:0, 
           avg: { $avg: "$funding_rounds.raised_amount" }} },
{ $sort: { avg: -1 } }
] );
```

But it is giving error:

> ```
> Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0 ()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37 ([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866 @(shell):8
>
> uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {   "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$avg'",    "code" : 15999,     "ok" : 0 }
> ```

and I running this query on robomongo?

Answer (score 0):

In the mongoDB documentation we can read that:

[The $avg is an accumulator operator available only in the $group stage.](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

So to use `$avg` you need to be in a `$group` stage.